# Android added Fragment to screen, but taps fall through new Fragment view to the previous one

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working with Fragments for the first time and running into a weird behavior. I have an activity with a Fragment covering the entire view. It contains a ListView. When I tap on an item in the ListView, I want to show a details fragment which contains information about that item.

This is how I'm presenting the new fragment view:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

DetailsFragment fragment = new DetailsFragment();
transaction.add(R.id.viewRoot, fragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                .addToBackStack("Details").commit();
```

R.id.viewRoot is the id of the root layout in the first Fragment's layout xml, so the new Fragment fills the entire screen.

My Problem: When the new fragment is visible and covering the entire screen, any clicks or taps which land on the background (i.e. not hitting a button or textfield on the new fragment) appear to be going through the view and landing on the first fragment. So, I tap on a ListView item, which causes the DetailsFragment to get added to the screen. Then when I tap on the background of the DetailsFragment, that tap falls through and lands on the ListView causing another DetailsFragment to be added for whatever item I happened to hit behind the scenes.

Am I adding my new fragment incorrectly? Why are my clicks/taps falling through?

EDIT for caiuspb:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public void pushNewFragment(Fragment fragment, String description) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        transaction.remove(this);
        transaction.add(R.id.viewRoot, fragment).setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
                        .addToBackStack(description).commit();
    }

}
```

All of my fragments extend my BaseFragment class.

Comment: have you tried transaction.replace(R.id.viewRoot, fragment)?

Comment: I hadn't before, but I just tried it but it behaves the same way.

Comment: Found same problem -> seems to be resolved with this simple workaround : added a transparent button behind everything in the fragment, to catch every tap which will otherwise go through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experimented with the suggestions I received, but none of them worked. In the end, my solution was to add an OnTouchListener to the root view of my subfragments which discarded all touches.

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: The easiest way is just add clickable="true" for root XML view of new Fragment.

Comment: @iBog Thank you. This was the laziest and the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

There is another post here on StackOverflow about that strange Fragment behaviour. Try to remove your Fragment before you add it because the replace Method seems to be buggy

edit:
Move the Fragment logic into your Activity because your activity contains your Fragments. Today I tried to use the FragmentActivity and Fragments from the Android Support Library. Now I can use the replace method withouht any bugs. This is my approach and this works:

```
public class DashActivity extends FragmentActivity{
...
private void changeRightFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Loading Fragment into container: " + fragment.getClass().toString());
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.rightfrag, fragment);
        // Add a transition effect
        ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_FADE);
        // Add the Fragment to the BackStack so it can be restored by
        // pressing the Back button
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
    ...
public void setUserFragment(User user) {
    UserFragment fragment = new UserFragment(user);
    changeRightFragment(fragment);
}
```

So if you want to invoke a changeFragment method from inside your Fragment use a callback mechanism to the Activity

Comment: are you trying to change your fragment from inside your fragment? In my opinion you should put the fragment logic inside your activity

Comment: If I remove() my first fragment before adding the new fragment... when the user hits back from the second fragment... the 1st fragment won't be there anymore waiting for them. I don't want to do that, I want to create a stack (similar to a UINavigationController from iOS).

Comment: you can put your fragment on the stack by executing '  fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);' before you commit your changes. The remove() method just removes your fragment from the container but does not delete your stack

Comment: I'm not calling replace() though, I'm calling add(). If I do switch to using remove and then add, does that mean I'm going to have to add the fragment back to the container whenever I call back from the child fragment?

Comment: its quite difficult to help you because your post contains just a snippet of your program. You have to remove your "ListFragment" before you add your Detailsfragment to the container. Remove() does not kill you Fragment it just removes the Fragment from it's container. So if you use remove() and add() and press the back button inside your DetailsFragment, the DetailsFragment will be killed and you should see your ListFragment.
However it seems not like you really use the beneftis of Fragments. -> http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: What other code could I show to help understand what I'm doing and trying to do? I read through the link and it's talking about activities, not fragments. If I understand correctly, I can use multiple fragments per activity so that my activity can support phones and tablets. On the tablet, perhaps all of my fragments will be visible at the same time, but on the phone just one at a time.

Comment: I'll try removing the existing fragment before adding the new one, but it seems counterintuitive to me.

Comment: You have to remove it from a Container if you do not want to load another activity. If you just add a Fragment on the top of another one you get this strange behaviour that you cann look though a fragment. As long as you add your fragment on the backstack you dont have to worry

Comment: I added a transaction.remove() call for my current fragment, but I'm still seeing the same pass-through behavior. I've edited my original post above to add the code I'm using to push a new fragment onto the stack so you can see what I'm doing.

Comment: Btw, I appreciate the time you've spent with me here. Your suggestion for this problem doesn't appear to be helping so I didn't want to vote it up, but I looked through your answers to other questions and voted one of those up instead.